# Access: Overflow Error with UNION but not with UNION ALL or Individual Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

Why would I get an overflow error when using a UNION query and not with UNION ALL?? The query on each side of the UNION works fine on its own and the tables each query are acting on are identical i.e. a live data table and an archived data table which have the exact same structure.

Query Works:

```
SELECT Format(CVDate([DateID] & " " & [TimeID]),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss") & "-" & [RecNum] AS DateTimeRecNumID, 
    [QC Records].WONum, 
    [QC Records].InspName1, 
    [QC Records].QtyInsp, 
    Nz([008],0)+Nz([011],0)+Nz([012],0)+Nz([013],0)+Nz([014],0)+Nz([015],0)+Nz([016],0)+Nz([017],0)+Nz([018],0)+Nz([019],0)+Nz([020],0)+Nz([022],0)+Nz([023],0)+Nz([029],0)+Nz([035],0)+Nz([036],0)+Nz([037],0)+Nz([040],0)+Nz([041],0)+Nz([044],0)+Nz([045],0)+Nz([046],0)+Nz([047],0)+Nz([048],0)+Nz([050],0)+Nz([052],0)+Nz([055],0)+Nz([057],0)+Nz([059],0)+Nz([060],0)+Nz([062],0)+Nz([064],0)+Nz([066],0)+Nz([070],0)+Nz([072],0)+Nz([075],0)+Nz([077],0)+Nz([080],0)+Nz([081],0)+Nz([082],0)+Nz([083],0)+Nz([084],0)+Nz([085],0)+Nz([086],0)+Nz([088],0)+Nz([095],0)+Nz([096],0)+Nz([097],0)+Nz([111],0)+Nz([113],0)+Nz([115],0)+Nz([116],0)+Nz([117],0)+Nz([118],0)+Nz([119],0)+Nz([120],0)+Nz([121],0)+Nz([122],0)+Nz([123],0)+Nz([124],0)+Nz([125],0)+Nz([126],0)+Nz([127],0)+Nz([128],0)+Nz([129],0)+Nz([130],0)+Nz([130],0) AS SumFaults,
    1-([SumFaults]/[QtyInsp]) AS PassRate,
    [QC Records].ItemNum
FROM [QC Records]
WHERE ((([QC Records].ProdSrc)="Production"))
UNION ALL
SELECT Format(CVDate([DateID] & " " & [TimeID]),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss") & "-" & [RecNum] AS DateTimeRecNumID,
    [QC Records (Archive)].WONum,
    [QC Records (Archive)].InspName1,
    [QC Records (Archive)].QtyInsp,
    Nz([008],0)+Nz([011],0)+Nz([012],0)+Nz([013],0)+Nz([014],0)+Nz([015],0)+Nz([016],0)+Nz([017],0)+Nz([018],0)+Nz([019],0)+Nz([020],0)+Nz([022],0)+Nz([023],0)+Nz([029],0)+Nz([035],0)+Nz([036],0)+Nz([037],0)+Nz([040],0)+Nz([041],0)+Nz([044],0)+Nz([045],0)+Nz([046],0)+Nz([047],0)+Nz([048],0)+Nz([050],0)+Nz([052],0)+Nz([055],0)+Nz([057],0)+Nz([059],0)+Nz([060],0)+Nz([062],0)+Nz([064],0)+Nz([066],0)+Nz([070],0)+Nz([072],0)+Nz([075],0)+Nz([077],0)+Nz([080],0)+Nz([081],0)+Nz([082],0)+Nz([083],0)+Nz([084],0)+Nz([085],0)+Nz([086],0)+Nz([088],0)+Nz([095],0)+Nz([096],0)+Nz([097],0)+Nz([111],0)+Nz([113],0)+Nz([115],0)+Nz([116],0)+Nz([117],0)+Nz([118],0)+Nz([119],0)+Nz([120],0)+Nz([121],0)+Nz([122],0)+Nz([123],0)+Nz([124],0)+Nz([125],0)+Nz([126],0)+Nz([127],0)+Nz([128],0)+Nz([129],0)+Nz([130],0)+Nz([130],0) AS SumFaults,
    1-([SumFaults]/[QtyInsp]) AS PassRate,
    [QC Records (Archive)].ItemNum
FROM [QC Records (Archive)]
WHERE ((([QC Records (Archive)].ProdSrc)="Production"));
```

Doesn't Work (difference being the 'ALL' after UNION:

```
SELECT Format(CVDate([DateID] & " " & [TimeID]),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss") & "-" & [RecNum] AS DateTimeRecNumID, 
    [QC Records].WONum, 
    [QC Records].InspName1, 
    [QC Records].QtyInsp, 
    Nz([008],0)+Nz([011],0)+Nz([012],0)+Nz([013],0)+Nz([014],0)+Nz([015],0)+Nz([016],0)+Nz([017],0)+Nz([018],0)+Nz([019],0)+Nz([020],0)+Nz([022],0)+Nz([023],0)+Nz([029],0)+Nz([035],0)+Nz([036],0)+Nz([037],0)+Nz([040],0)+Nz([041],0)+Nz([044],0)+Nz([045],0)+Nz([046],0)+Nz([047],0)+Nz([048],0)+Nz([050],0)+Nz([052],0)+Nz([055],0)+Nz([057],0)+Nz([059],0)+Nz([060],0)+Nz([062],0)+Nz([064],0)+Nz([066],0)+Nz([070],0)+Nz([072],0)+Nz([075],0)+Nz([077],0)+Nz([080],0)+Nz([081],0)+Nz([082],0)+Nz([083],0)+Nz([084],0)+Nz([085],0)+Nz([086],0)+Nz([088],0)+Nz([095],0)+Nz([096],0)+Nz([097],0)+Nz([111],0)+Nz([113],0)+Nz([115],0)+Nz([116],0)+Nz([117],0)+Nz([118],0)+Nz([119],0)+Nz([120],0)+Nz([121],0)+Nz([122],0)+Nz([123],0)+Nz([124],0)+Nz([125],0)+Nz([126],0)+Nz([127],0)+Nz([128],0)+Nz([129],0)+Nz([130],0)+Nz([130],0) AS SumFaults,
    1-([SumFaults]/[QtyInsp]) AS PassRate,
    [QC Records].ItemNum
FROM [QC Records]
WHERE ((([QC Records].ProdSrc)="Production"))
UNION  
SELECT Format(CVDate([DateID] & " " & [TimeID]),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss") & "-" & [RecNum] AS DateTimeRecNumID,
    [QC Records (Archive)].WONum,
    [QC Records (Archive)].InspName1,
    [QC Records (Archive)].QtyInsp,
    Nz([008],0)+Nz([011],0)+Nz([012],0)+Nz([013],0)+Nz([014],0)+Nz([015],0)+Nz([016],0)+Nz([017],0)+Nz([018],0)+Nz([019],0)+Nz([020],0)+Nz([022],0)+Nz([023],0)+Nz([029],0)+Nz([035],0)+Nz([036],0)+Nz([037],0)+Nz([040],0)+Nz([041],0)+Nz([044],0)+Nz([045],0)+Nz([046],0)+Nz([047],0)+Nz([048],0)+Nz([050],0)+Nz([052],0)+Nz([055],0)+Nz([057],0)+Nz([059],0)+Nz([060],0)+Nz([062],0)+Nz([064],0)+Nz([066],0)+Nz([070],0)+Nz([072],0)+Nz([075],0)+Nz([077],0)+Nz([080],0)+Nz([081],0)+Nz([082],0)+Nz([083],0)+Nz([084],0)+Nz([085],0)+Nz([086],0)+Nz([088],0)+Nz([095],0)+Nz([096],0)+Nz([097],0)+Nz([111],0)+Nz([113],0)+Nz([115],0)+Nz([116],0)+Nz([117],0)+Nz([118],0)+Nz([119],0)+Nz([120],0)+Nz([121],0)+Nz([122],0)+Nz([123],0)+Nz([124],0)+Nz([125],0)+Nz([126],0)+Nz([127],0)+Nz([128],0)+Nz([129],0)+Nz([130],0)+Nz([130],0) AS SumFaults,
    1-([SumFaults]/[QtyInsp]) AS PassRate,
    [QC Records (Archive)].ItemNum
FROM [QC Records (Archive)]
WHERE ((([QC Records (Archive)].ProdSrc)="Production"));
```

Error is 'Overflow'

I've also tried doing a SELECT DISTINCT query on the UNION ALL query and it's giving me the 'Overflow' error too...??

Comment: Can you give us some more details about the queries and the tables?

Comment: And also please provide the error message.

Comment: Also is it possible to respond to multiple comment authors together e.g. @Gidil @Igor??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Why would I get an overflow error when using a UNION query and not with UNION ALL??"*

You indicated you're aware that `UNION` returns only distinct rows, and `UNION ALL` returns all rows including duplicates.  With just `UNION`, the db engine must apply a sort to the initial working set so that it can identify which are the duplicate rows and eliminate them from the final result set.  That sort operation imposes a significant additional burden on the db engine, which incidentally explains why `UNION ALL` is always faster than `UNION`, quite often dramatically faster.

In your case, the individual `SELECT` statements already impose an unusual burden on the db engine.  Never before have I seen an Access query which uses `Nz()` 67 times and adds all those values to derive one calculated field. And the db engine must do that work again for every row of each source table.

Access can cope with that workload for one `SELECT`.  And it can still cope when you `UNION ALL` two of them.  But Access chokes when you impose the sort requirement required for `UNION`.

If your next question is *"What can I do instead?"*, I will suggest you first look at the source tables.  The complexity of your `SELECT` queries is a consequence of the table design.  If changes there are out of the question, at least consider whether you can run `UPDATE` statements to replace Null with 0 in the source tables; that might ease the burden enough to `UNION` simpler (ie without all those `Nz` calls) `SELECT` queries successfully.

As a final resort, consider appending the result set from each `SELECT` into a scratch table:

```sql
INSERT INTO scratch_table
    (
        DateTimeRecNumID,
        WONum,
        InspName1,
        QtyInsp,
        SumFaults,
        PassRate,
        ItemNum
    )
SELECT ...
```

Then Access may be able to deal with ...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM scratch_table;
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation HansUp. I'm actually in the process of redesigning the whole DB as it's very poorly designed but I got a request to give access to the archived data ASAP so I was trying to bodge something temporary together until I'm ready to roll out the improved version. I reckon I'll try and remove the Nz's first and failing that will go with the scratch table idea. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your source field contains some #Num! caused by divisions by 0 other errors. Make sure that there is no error in the records of the queries you want to make the union with, not only for the top results. You may need to scroll or use filters to check this hypothesis.